# Getting the numeric value of an array after using in_array

Tags: php, arrays

When using:

```
if (in_array("boots", $products)) {
 echo "Boots found";
}
```

Lets say this comes back as True, then how can I find the numeric value of where "boots" is in my $products array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`array_search` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php):

```
$key = array_search('boots', $products);
```

The best part is, you can use `array_search` *instead* of `in_array`, because it returns `FALSE` if the needle can't be found in the haystack.